# How to add an image on top of a fixed position container?

Tags: css

I would like to create a following shaped notice bar on the bottom of my webpage (sticky).

[image: notice bar, with a top border wavy]

Here is my HTML

```
   <div class="notice-container">
      <div class="wave"></div>
      <div>
        <p>Content here</p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

And here is my CSS, I tried several things, but here is the latest:

```
        .notice-container {
          display: block;
          height: auto;
          background-color: #ccc;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          width: 100%;
        }
        .wave:after {
          content: "";
          background-image: url('../wave.png');
          background-repeat: repeat-x;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          margin: -30px;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }
```

Since the container has a position: fixed, how can I get the repeat-x work on the wave? I would like to display the background-image on top of the container div.

Comment: Specify width of background image and enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo element needs `display: block;` and also a specified `height` attribute. Since the value `auto` would just tell it to extend to fit its contents (and it has none), then the `height` value would remain `0`.

```
.wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; /* <- Add this */
  background-image: url('../wave.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: -30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Or whatever your wave.png requires */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your url and justice the sizes of image in `background-size`. Also do not forget to change needed height of pseudo element which is also needs to configure `margin-top` and `top`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
footer:after {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:-20px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4HMY.png);
  background-size: 10% 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```